# checkboxlist items as checked by default in codebehind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind, checkboxlist

In my page I have a `CheckBoxList` control and I have 7 items on it. I would like to set those 7 items as checked in my `Page_load` codebihind.

my page:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="WeeklyCondition" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Sat</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Sun</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Mon</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Tue</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="5">Wed</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="6">Thu</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="7">Fri</asp:ListItem>

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check some of those with some condition, You can use something like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if(someCondition)
           CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1315026.aspx?How%20can%20I%20set%20checkboxlist%20items%20as%20checked%20by%20default)

Comment: Better yet, do it in the checkboxlist's DataBound event.

Answer (score 12):

You can use loop to *iterate* through the items collection of `CheckBoxList` and change the `Selected` property.

```
foreach (ListItem item in WeeklyCondition.Items) 
    item.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

How can I set checkboxlist items as checked by default

First way:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList1">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Second way:

Page File:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxList">
    <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBoxList.Items[i].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item1</asp:ListItem>
```

[How can I set checkboxlist items as checked by default](https://forums.asp.net/t/1315026.aspx?How%20can%20I%20set%20checkboxlist%20items%20as%20checked%20by%20default)

Comment: OK I am loading a simple table with values that are all checked by default.  The loop to read is below. The critical part I think you want is:  cblAnalyteGroup.Items.Add(dRow.Item("AnalyteGroupName").Selected)

The code for the page is very limited:
<asp:CheckBoxList SelectionMode="Multiple" ID="cblAnalyteGroup" runat="server" />

For Each dRow As DataRow In cblAnalyteGroup.DataSource.Rows
      cblAnalyteGroup.Items.Add(dRow.Item("AnalyteGroupName").Selected)
 Next