# how to check particular item on checkboxlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

here is the code that I have used to check the items on string match but it is not working

```
foreach(ListItem li in Checklistbox1.Items)
{
    if(li.text == "John")
     {
         li.selected = true;
     }
}
```

please help me in solving this problem

Comment: What is the error/exception here ? Not working in terms of what ?

Comment: Hi, I have posted ans. you just need to use "Value" in place of text.

Comment: @RahulNikate can you share the code how to do it in for loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [checkboxlist items as checked by default in codebehind asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978384/checkboxlist-items-as-checked-by-default-in-codebehind-asp-net)

Comment: @HarveySpecter am not getting any error just not able to change checkboxstate in checklistbox

Comment: @Supreethsup You need to add some more code like aspx code for Checkboxlist and how you are binding it

Comment: where is this code on page load on change event where ?

Comment: @JaiminSoni this code is on another button click event which will uncheck the matched employee name in checklistbox

Comment: so what happen there its not working as per solution ? its give error ? have check that using debugging ?

Answer (score 8):

You can try like this without loop:

```
Checklistbox1.Items.FindByValue("John").Selected = true;
```

or you can try this:

```
foreach(ListItem li in Checklistbox1.Items)
{
    if(li.Value == "John")
     {
         li.selected = true;
     }
}
```

or you can try like this:

```
foreach (var item in Checklistbox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
        .Where (li => li.Value == "John"))
   item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: @Adil:- Yes that is not required. Updated that!

Comment: but he want to check text not value.

Answer (score 0):

Without loop :

```
void yourbutton_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Checklistbox1.Items.FindByText("John").Selected = true;
}
```

Using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(ListItem li in Checklistbox1.Items)
{
    if(li.Text == "John")
    {
        li.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Using `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Checklistbox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     if(Checklistbox1.Items[i].Text == "John")
     {
          Checklistbox1.Items[i].Selected = true;
     }       
}
```

Comment: @Supreethsup Where are you binding DataSource to Checkboxlist

Comment: on loaditems button click @RahulNikate

Comment: OP said its `text` to be compared. Why do you assume it to be `value`?

Comment: @JaiminSoni What's difference between your answer and OP's question

Comment: You all !!!! i have try this code on my page and its working fine. I have check this on page load.